# No se puede encontrar una parte de la ruta de acceso

Tags: c#

Buenos días a todos, nuevamente necesito de su apoyo, ya que al intentar crear un archivo de texto por medio de ***C#*** y guardarlo en un servidor, al cual accedo por medio de una unidad en red me genera esta excepción

> No se puede encontrar una parte de la ruta de acceso
>   'C:\172.69.17.30\c$\Achivo'

El detalle esta en que al enviarlo a mi disco local ***C:\Achivo*** el archivo se crea de forma correcta, alguien tiene idea de que puede estar sucediendo.

Gracias de nuevo por su apoyo.

Este es el código:

```
int nolines = 100;
string lines = "";
for (int i = 0; i <= nolines; i++)
{
      lines = "01-09-2016;01-09-2016;BANCO ;rfc1";
}           
System.IO.StreamWriter filelocal = new System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\\Archivo\\test.tx");
System.IO.StreamWriter fileserver = new System.IO.StreamWriter("\\172.69.17.30\\c$\\Archivo\\test.tx");//\\172.69.17.30\\c$\\Achivo
filelocal.WriteLine(lines);
filelocal.Close();
fileserver.WriteLine(lines);
fileserver.Close();
```

Comment: Me confundo un poco, sí tienes que enviarlo a una unidad de red, no creo que tengas que ingresar a la unidad C, pues esta es una unidad local, deberías aclarar un poco eso, además incluir tu código, pues pueden haber muchas razones por las cuales tu código falle.

Comment: Tengo que guardar el archivo de forma local y crear una copia en el servidor para tenerla como respaldo.

Comment: Podrías agregar tu código por favor.

Comment: si bueno esta mal, la ruta de red no puede comenzar con C:\

Comment: Cuando me lanza la excepción esa es la ruta que me muestra

Comment: Gracias gbianchi, Randall Sandoval, sstan

Answer (score 8, accepted):

El problema está con esta cadena:

```
"\\172.69.17.30\\c$\\Archivo\\test.tx"
```

Te falta otro doble `\\` en frente:

```
"\\\\172.69.17.30\\c$\\Archivo\\test.tx"
```

o también puedes usar el estilo [*literal de cadena textual*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx) con el símbolo `@` en frente. Esto te evita la confusión con tener que duplicar los `\`:

```
@"\\172.69.17.30\c$\Archivo\test.tx"
```

Comment: totalmente de acuerdo con @sstan voto arriba

Comment: Muchas gracias era la opción de agregar dos slash mas